# IsAuthenticated Remains True after the Cookie is expired in ASP.NET Core Identity with .NET 6 Blazor Project

Tags: blazor

I am developing an application on .NET 6 Blazor Server side. For authentication, I have been using **asp.net core Identity**. Here is my login code:

```
var LoginResult = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.UserName, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
if (LoginResult.Succeeded)
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>()
    {
        new Claim("UserId", createdUser?.Id),
        new Claim("UserName", createdUser?.UserName),
        new Claim("OrganizationId", createdUser?.OrganizationId),
        new Claim("OrganizationName", OrganizationName)
    };

    var claimsPrincipal = await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(createdUser);
    var claimResult = claimsPrincipal.Claims.ToList();

    if (claims != null && claims.Count > 0)
    {
        await _userManager.AddClaimsAsync(createdUser, claims.ToList());                            
    }

    await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(createdUser);

    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
}
```

In my **Program.cs** file I have set the below settings so that the **Cookie expires** after a certain amount of time. Here is the code:

```
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    // Cookie settings
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.Name = "Horus";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

    options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
    options.LogoutPath = "/Identity/account/logout";
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

I have this code (**options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)**;) for cookie expire.

Now I have a Service class and there I have a method that checks whether the user is authenticated or not. Here is the code:

```
public class UserInfoService : IUserInfoService
{
    private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider _authProvider; 

    public UserInfoService(AuthenticationStateProvider authProvider,)
    {
        _authProvider = authProvider;
    }

    public async Task<bool> IsAuthenticated()
    {
        var auth = await _authProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = auth.User;   
        return (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated);
    }
}
```

Now in every Razor page of my Blazor project, in the **OnInitializedAsync** function I have called  **IsAuthenticated** function to see the user is authenticated. But the problem is even the **cookie expires time** is over **IsAuthenticated** returns true. But if I refresh the page the page redirects to the login page.

I have also used the below code as alternate:

```
[Inject] IHttpContextAccessor Context { get; set; }
var authenticateResult = Context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
```

This also not works. I don't know what is the problem. Can anyone suggest me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi @mnu-nasir, How is your authentication or authorization middleware order?

Comment: app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

Comment: Hi @mnu-nasir, I think the reason why the IsAuthenticated is always the same is because there is no HttpContext in client-side Blazor. Pls check this [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/12601#issuecomment-525804729) to check.

Comment: I have also tried with AuthenticationStateProvider

Comment: Hi @mnu-nasir, you can try to set `option.CloseOnAuthenticationExpiration = true;` in the `app.MapBlazorHub` middleware.

Comment: It's not working. This code does not support in blazor

Comment: Hi, are you sure you use .net 6 blazor server? The code is :`app.MapBlazorHub(option =>
{
    option.CloseOnAuthenticationExpiration = true;
});`. It supports in blazor.